# CRUD MVC web application on top of Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I developed a Web API 2 web service, that is providing a lot of endpoints, where currently several pages and modules are asking for information.

This approach is good sinceI'm providing a lot of data in a good way to a lot of different clients.

Now, I'd like to create a simple CRUD page by myself to show this information.

I'd like to start using ASP.NET 5, and I'm start looking for tutorial and resources, but I found info only about EF interaction, that is not my case.

Can you help to collect resources to study and reach my goal?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: If you want to call  webapi services from backend code (i.e. Controller) search for HttpClient. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client. But I doubt this is a good way to go. Webapis are better suited to interact with clients (js) more than backend

Comment: Actually I want to have a responsive web app to show (for now) and manipulate these entities, since all the webservice functionalities are already deployed and usable

Comment: @tede24 - the link is not working. Also, I am not sure, why do you think the Web APIs are more suited to be called by client code? In that case, do you mean, we should have different mechanism for calls from client (js) and back-end (controller actions)? I generally call Web APIs from both client-side and back-end and they work without any issues. I have seen many examples as well and I guess it is a standard practice.

Comment: Actually, my web service endpoints are already called by both (client and server side). what I was looking for is a good starting point or a collection of resources to start using this exposed data more properly

Answer (score 1):

I have written an application of exactly this architecture; an ASP.NET 5.0 MVC application using a ASP.NET 4.5 Web API 2 for CRUD operations.

As other folks have said, the API call itself can be achieved via HttpClient.

The way I've created the MVC pages in this scenario before is to use scaffolding against your model (Right click project > Add > New Scaffolded Item > MVC controller etc), but substitute the Entity Framework code in the controller with your own API calls. This way you get the scaffolded views and controller structure.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment if you want to show a responsive web app to manipulate these entities then create a SPA and call the Web API directly.  To do this you could use any of the following frameworks:

http://www.angular.js

https://facebook.github.io/react/

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui